# What does "LifeCycle expectations" mean in SQALE?

Tags: static-analysis, code-metrics

I was going through [this wiki article on SQALE(Software Quality Assessment based on Lifecycle Expectations)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQALE). The *Software Quality assurance* part of it is clear. But I am unable to understand the "*based on LifeCycle expectations*" part of the model. Can someone please explain in a clear to understand way the *LifeCycle expectations* part.

Answer (score 0):

Ever since I first encountered SQALE, I've suspected that the creators were working backward from the acronym, and "lifecycle expectations" was the best that they could come up with that wasn't already taken.  (There are other similarly acronymed guidelines or methodologies in the software quality space, such as [Squale](http://www.squale.org/) and [SQuaRE](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=35683)).

All but the most rudimentary models of software quality incorporate the notion of quality over the full lifecycle of a software product (from "gleam in someone's eye" phase all the way through eventual decomissioning), not just its state at the time of initial shipping.

Such models also acknowledge that the desirable investment in any given aspect of software quality (e.g.: maintainability) is not equal for all software products.   For example, one would tend to make very different decisions in maintainability investments for a boxed-style software product one hopes to sell (and upgrade) for years vs for a short-term marketing promo site that will be decomissioned one month after it goes live.

So...  All that "lifecycle expectations" bit probably implies is something along the lines of covering software quality aspects that affect multiple part of the lifecycle of a product, as well as allowing adjustment/calibration to different expectations for the various quality characteristics.

If you're interested in how the SQALE authors might have meant this (assuming they weren't only trying to shoehorn the name into the acronym), there are a few hints in the SQALE manual that can be downloaded from http://www.sqale.org/download.  They seem to feel that they've done something novel and useful in projecting the ISO/IEC 9126 quality characteristics over a product lifecycle in a chronological order, and perhaps this is what the name is meant to reflect.

BTW, if you're interested in software quality and want to understand this sort of quality modeling in more depth, I'd recommend taking a look at SQuaRE (incl. the parts of ISO/IEC 9126 for which there are no SQuaRE replacements yet).  It's not necessarily the most exciting reading, but I find that it provides excellent background for evaluating the utility of various quality methodologies and tools.